ERROR in file_io_posix.cc, trying to locate scaling_cur_freq and scaling_max_freq and couldn't find it
I'm trying to execute a container based on ubuntu 20.04 and some additional dependencies.
Ended up in an error where the project (something external) is looking for files/programs such as the below.
Problem
I tried looking for installing these modules but couldn't find it anywhere. can someone help me out here. This error is coming once I start some the proprietery docker container. Couldn't figure out if this is from docker or the linux machine which I'm working. Tried looking in other places in stack overflow but no solution is available.
Some solutions:
Error installing Chrome on AWS EC2 Linux Instance: scaling_cur_freq & scaling_max_freq not found --> has the same error but the fix they have is different.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
